# Mount NTFS image file created using partimage

Tags: partition, mount, ntfs, partimage

From an old disk which I don't have at hand, I have created a file named winxp.img  using `partimage`.  As the filename suggests, the partition contained Windows XP and was formatted with NTFS.

(The file contains only a 4.6 GiB NTFS partition, not the whole disk.)

How can I access the files inside this image without restoring it onto a physical disk?

Comment: [This is an old request.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/partimage-ng/+bug/202512) I don't know that anything came of it.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [partimage documentation](http://www.partimage.org/Partimage-manual_Partition_Image_Internals#How_are_the_partitions_read.2Fwritten)<sup>1</sup>,

> (...) It is also impossible to extract a file from an image.

But need not despair! With the power of Unix philosophy (*"Everything is a file"*), you can access the files without the need to allocate disc space for a separate partition. And here's how:

..0. You say your image created with `partimage` is named **`winxp.img`** and it holds the backup of a **4.6 GiB** NTFS partition. Fine. You have more than 4.6 GiB of free space on your Linux system? Perfect! (Otherwise, get some free space.) **You can restore the contents of `partimage` archive to a "dummy" file that will pretend to be a real partition.**

1. First, you need to **create an empty file** of at least 4.6 GiB size:

   ```
   dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy_disk.raw bs=1M count=4711
   ```

   *<sub>(The value of `count` parameter comes from rounding up `1024*4.6` to achieve an amount above 4.6 GiB. For an exact value, you would need to know the bytesize of the original partition - but if you have enough free space, you can simply use `5K` instead, to be on the safe side.)</sub>*

   Now, tell `partimage` to restore your NTFS filesystem to that dummy space. What? It refuses to treat a normal file as hard drive partition? No problem - if Unix says *"Everything is a file"*, then a disk handle such as `/dev/sda1` is a file also - so we just need to reverse this situation and supply a "block device" type of file to `partimage` - and that is where **loopback device** construct comes in handy (read on).
2. Create a **loopback device** attached to your newly created dummy disk (this needs root privileges on most systems, therefore `sudo` is used):

   ```
   sudo losetup -f --show dummy_disk.raw
   ```

   The command will output something like `/dev/loop0` - that is the loopback device name you need to supply to `partimage` instead of real partition. You can also check that the loopback device is attached to your file by running `losetup -a` - this is of course optional.
3. Run `partimage` to **restore** the archived filesystem to the dummy file (replace `/dev/loop0` with the name you got in the previous step) :

   ```
   partimage restore /dev/loop0 winxp.img
   ```

   Once it finishes successfully, your `dummy_disk.raw` file will contain the restored NTFS filesystem! You just need to mount it now, in order to access the files:
4. **Mount** the dummy. You will just need an empty directory for this. You can create it with `mkdir mountpoint` or use an existing one. There are two alternative ways to mount the filesytem:

   ```
   sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/loop0 mountpoint
   ```

   (replace `/dev/loop0` with the device name you got previously)

   **OR**

   ```
   sudo mount -o loop -t ntfs-3g dummy_disk.raw mountpoint
   ```

   The former method will use the existing loopback device, while the latter will automatically create a new one (resource usage difference is negligible).

That's it! The contents of your archive are now accessible under the `mountpoint` directory.

*Side note: For the future tasks of archiving filesystems, consider using a more up-to-date tool, such as [FSAsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Main_Page). I'm not saying it's perfect, but at least it is still maintained. You can check the differences between those two tools at [the FSArchiver wiki page](http://www.fsarchiver.org/Fsarchiver_vs_partimage).*

---

*<sub><sup>1</sup> This might be slightly inaccurate, since the software is unmaintained and the [website lists that page of documentation as "Outdated"](http://www.partimage.org/Partimage-manual).</sub>*

Comment: How do you disconnect the loop device (i.e. `/dev/loop0`) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly as there is no "partimagefs" solution that I'm aware. You could check fuse tools but I think there's an easier way...

You can use a virtual disk (with KVM, qemu, VirtualBox) and let partimage unpack the image there. If you use the raw format you can then safely mount it.

The necessary steps are described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Mounting_an_image_on_the_host)

Comment: The `offset=32256` as described on the page you're referring to, is only required when using an entire disk image. According to Alois, this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a NTFS volume handy, but this may help you forward:

```
mount -t ntfs -o loop,ro /path/to/winxp.img /mnt
```

Where `/mnt` is an unused mountpoint. Many distributions have `/mnt` available, but you can easily create another one when necessary. `ro` indicates 'read-only' which is a good plan when you don't want your image being changed.

Comment: It isn't a raw image, so this won't work

Comment: You may try something like this before raw mount for compressed image:
`nbdkit -v -r --no-fork -i 127.0.0.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nbdkit/plugins/nbdkit-gzip-plugin.so file='/path/to/compressed/image.img.aa'`
and then
`nbd-client -nofork 127.0.0.1 10809 /dev/nbd0` ,
and then mount raw image.img (which on /dev/nbd0) without loops.